# Using generated php variable as name for html <input> object in loop

Tags: php, html

On the first page (index.php) I wrote this:

```
<?php   
echo '<form action="test.php" method="get">';
$x=0;
while($x<5){
$x++;
$test='tester'.$x;
echo '<input type="text" name="$test"><br>';
};
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
?>
```

on the second page (test.php) I wrote this:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['tester1'];
echo $_POST['tester2'];
echo $_POST['tester3'];
echo $_POST['tester4'];
echo $_POST['tester5'];
?>
```

and when I tested it I got these errors

> Notice: Undefined index: tester1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined index: tester2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: tester3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: tester4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: tester5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6

The code below is an example for the real code being meant for users to fill in a number. I want to use these numbers later for calculations so they all need an unique name. The `<input>` objects are generated via a loop, the amount of times the loop runs is specified by the amount of rows in a database.

Comment: In single-quotes, PHP variables are not passed as variables, but the actual text will be output. It should look like `echo '<input type="text" name="'.$test.'"><br>';`

Comment: we tested this and it didnt work

Comment: You also have `method="get"`, so they are passed in the URL instead over POST. Change it to `method="POST"`. Apply both changes of what I commented, that *should* work.

Comment: okay thanks it worked

Comment: like what @Qirel said, these are correction you need to make, on top of it, i hope you didn't miss out your closing form tag.

Comment: You can use `<input type="text" name="$test"> `without need to concatenate the variable. Only necessary concatenate it if you working as array. So the treatment is different. Your problem is only `method = GET` inside your `<form>`tag defined.

Comment: @bcesars False, he's passing the string in single quotes, not double quotes (and if it was double-quotes, his string would produce errors, because he's using double-quotes for HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works (index.php):

```
<?php
    echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
    $x=0;
    while($x<5){
        $x++;
        $test='tester'.$x;
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$test.'"><br>';
    };
    echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
?>
```

Comment: Can't use `method="get"` when trying to retrieve them as POST in PHP.

Comment: yeah its because i had tried it with method get and post and I didnt change it right when i posted the question

Answer (score 1):

The two main issues are that you are using PHP variables inside single quotes, this doesn't pass the actual variable, but the actual name. As an example

```
$foo = "bar";
echo 'This is $foo';
```

would print

> This is $foo

If you use double-quotes, the variable's content would be passed,

```
$foo = "bar";
echo "This is $foo"; // You can also do the following: echo 'This is '.$foo;
```

would print

> This is bar

Secondly, you are using `method="get"` in your form, but trying to retrieve them as POST variables. This means that you have to change it to `method="POST"`.

---

Another alternative, is to create an array of elements, and use a loop in PHP to retrieve the values. An example given below. The first snippet generates a form with 5 input-fields as an array.

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <?php for ($x=0; $x<5; $x++) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="tester[]" />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And in PHP, loop through that array.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tester']) {
    // If the values are set, to avoid Undefined Index notices
    foreach ($_POST['tester'] as $value) {
        echo $value."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply append this code to the top of test.php

```
if(!isset($_POST['tester1']) || !isset($_POST['tester2']) ... etc){
     exit(0); //or do something to signal index.php of missing values
}
/* (the rest of the code */
```

When writing a dynamic page like this, you should always expect there to be a missing variable and code an escape so you never run into an error such as that.